# Primefaces Ajax listener is not getting called when rendered is used in Panel

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, conditional-rendering

Below is the code snippet that is being used. When i remove the rendered attribute from the below code, the listener is getting called. but with render, its not calling the listener.
My PrimaryContactHomeAddressBean bean is in RequestScope whereas AddressManagedBean is having ViewScope.

```
<p:outputPanel id="countyPanel">
            <p:panelGrid
                id="primaryContactHomeZipPanel" rendered="#{address.isMultipleCounty eq 'Yes'}">
                <h:outputLabel for="primaryContactHomeCounty">
                    </h:outputLabel>
                <p:selectOneMenu id="primaryContactHomeCounty"
                    value="#{addressManagedBean.countyName}">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{addressManagedBean.countyListDropdown}" />
                        <p:ajax listener="#{primaryContactHomeAddressBean.saveCountyName}" process="@this"  update="primaryContactHomecountyName" partialSubmit="true"></p:ajax>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <p:message for="primaryContactHomeCounty" />


            </p:panelGrid>
        </p:outputPanel>
```

Comment: You have no closing brace on `<h:outputLabel for="primaryContactHomeCounty"`

Comment: it was a typo. have added now.

Comment: What scope is `#{address}` in?

Comment: #{address} is in RequestScope.

Comment: do you have an enclosing `h:form`?

Comment: Yes, i do have enclosing h:form.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this issue by moving `isMultipleCounty` variable to a `ViewScoped` Bean i.e. `AddressManagedBean.`

Answer (score -1):

This line does not follow the JavaBean standards.

```
rendered="#{address.isMultipleCounty eq 'Yes'}"
```

If the getter begins with `is`, then it is supposed to return a boolean, but here you are checking for a String. If it is returning a boolean, then remove the `eq 'Yes'`, regardless rename it `multipleCounty`.

Comment: The code only doesn't work when you include the rendered, which has incorrect syntax in it? That sounds like the actual issue to me.

Comment: I agree that the Java standards are not met, but there is no compilation issue. Even if i use getMultipleCounty instead of isMultipleCounty, problem remains the same.

Comment: And just multipleCountry?

Comment: see, it doesn't matter how you name your variables. Its just the standards, we SHOULD follow for the better readibility. This issue is not because of the naming conventions.

Comment: I see where you are coming from. but, why is it working after changing the scope of the variable? if it has issues with `rendered="#{address.isMultipleCounty eq 'Yes'}"`